# Remotely reboot Windows when SSH into Bash on WSL

Tags: bash, ssh, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I set Bash to be the primary shell on Windows when I SSH, using the following:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\WINDOWS\System32\bash.exe" -PropertyType String -Force
```

Now, when I SSH into my Windows machine, I get a Bash shell (as I wanted). Ordinarily, if I want to reboot a Linux computer during an ssh session I can just type `reboot` in the terminal. But when I ssh into a Bash shell on Windows Subsystem for Linux and type `reboot` I get an error message:

> System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1).
> Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

I want to be able to reboot my Windows machine (not just the ssh-session) so that my computer returns to the grub menu (I am dual booting). Is there a way for me to do this? Can I, for example, type a command to spawn a Powershell session through ssh? Thanks!

Comment: [Shutdown - Shutdown the computer - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/shutdown.html)

Comment: `/r`        Shutdown and Restart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From some google searches, I've determined that you can type the following into a remote instance of WSL to achieve the result I want:

```
powershell.exe -command restart-computer
```